# ReactiveUI - Enable ValidatesOnDataErrors in code behind binding

Tags: system.reactive, reactiveui

I'm trying to be consistent in my Views and do all Binding in the code-behind with the IViewFor<> implementation. My bindings are all working great, except for my validation where I've implemented IDataErrorInfo on my ViewModel. Before when I just had the binding in my XAML I would include the `ValidatesOnDataErrors=True` (and the other needed options). Is there a way to do this in the code behind? Or maybe a better way altogether to accomplish this?